# Is sed's g command neccessary when used in the context of GNU Make Auto Dependency Generation

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I am reading Managing Projects with GNU Make Third Edition and in the section on auto dependency generation, I saw the following sed script

```
sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;
```

Here is the entire rule with the include

```
include $(subst .c,.d,$(SOURCES))

%.d: %.c
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
```

After studying this I was left wondering why the g command is used. So I copied everything to a new directory and removed all the target files and removed the g command from the sed script and executed make again. All was built without error. I also diffed the two directories, the one with the makefile using the g command in the sed script and the one without, and only that one difference popped out.

So I am wondering if there is some corner case where this g command comes into play.

What am I missing?

Thanks, Steven

A friend just pointed out that the g in 's,($*).o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' is not a sed command. Sed commands are separated by the semicolon. No wonder this made no sense in the context of sed commands.

The /g is a part of the regex and will cause it to look for all matches not just the first occurrence.

Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: the sed cmd seems to be searching for `.o` files, possibly separated with space or colons. So it seems to be a reasonable expectation that if you have 1 `.o`, you may have multiple `.o` files. I'm not going to try and guess which of `$(CPPFLAGS) $<` would actually have the list of `.o` files. You may have to test with more than 1 package to uncover that the `g` is doing your some good. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `g` option in a sed script performs the search for multiple times within a line. (In your case, the regular expression "`\($*\)\.o[ :]*`".) Without `g`, only the first match in the line is used.

Hence if there was only going to be at most one match anyway, the `g` makes no difference.